# Mac Programming to Android Programming

Tags: java, android

I would like to get started programming Android apps. I don't know Java, however I do know Objective-C and the Cocoa API. What would be the best resource to learn Android programming if you don't know Java, given my experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO the best way would be to get a basic Android book, in JAVA! I can tell you from my own experience, since I started to learn Java while learning Android.
Just grab a basic Android book and go ahead, some options:

- My first choice: http://pragprog.com/book/eband/hello-android
- A second one: http://commonsware.com/Android/

Cheers

Comment: The books seem very helpful... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are many paths that you can have to start transferring over.  Since you have been programming for a while (I will assume), you need a good brush-up on syntax.  My personal favorite for syntax and reference is the Professional series (it's a little dated) ([Here it is at Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471777102)) for example.  There are many other options you can choose and it may be best to go to a book store near you and research possible choices. Then, once I felt proficient in java, I would start looking at android programming books.  There are many choices ([Commonsware Android Book](http://commonsware.com/Android/)) is a good example.  You have to be careful though.  With the release of Ice Cream Sandwhich (Android 4.0), many of the programming styles you might learn are going to eventually be deprecated.  There are many books starting to come out (from now till like june) so I would personally spend the time learning the java syntax since it is somewhat different that C.

Some people might tell you to jump headlong, which is possible and can be somewhat of a short-cut, but in my experience, I have found that jumping immediately in can result in sloppy code as well as debugging nightmares.

GL with it and you can PM me if you have any more questions

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You better have, first, a very basic course in Java, platform-independent. Because Objective C is not really an object oriented language, though Java is. Then, when you are at ease with Java you may want to read a book like Pro Android 3 or some other book like that one.

Answer (score -3):

Probably the book *Objective C for Java developers* if you backtrack from Objective C to Java in its examples.